# Manipulating one video into multi outputs with FFmpeg results in no audio in the last output

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Using FFmpeg, I'm trying to do some filtering operations on one input video to scale it (out1), scale and trim it (out2).
This is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i "Robotica_1080.mkv" \
-filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[v1][v2]; \
[v1]scale=640:360,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vout1]; \
[v2]trim=10:15,scale=640:360,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vout2]; \
[0:a]asplit=2[a1][a2]; \
[a1]anull,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aout1]; \
[a2]atrim=10:15,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aout2]; \
[vout1][aout1]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[out1]; \
[vout2][aout2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[out2]" \
-map "[out1]" "1.mp4" \
-map "[out2]" "2.mp4"
```

1.mp4 is ok while 2.mp4 lasts 5 seconds as expected but without audio at all (the QuickTime inspector doesn't write the audio codec)

I tried to remove the trim/atrim filters, so the filter_complex parameter looked like this:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[v1][v2]; \
[v1]scale=640:360[vout1]; \
[v2]scale=640:360[vout2]; \
[0:a]asplit=2[a1][a2]; \
[a1]anull[aout1]; \
[a2]anull[aout2]; \
[vout1][aout1]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[out1]; \
[vout2][aout2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[out2]" \
```

but still no audio on 2.mp4

Can anyone give me a hint?

--EDIT--
This is the output from first ffmpeg command:

---

```
Mac-mini:~ Luca$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MediaGallery/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y \
> -i "/Users/Luca/Desktop/_TEMP UPLOAD/Video/Robotica_1080.mkv" \
> -filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[v1][v2]; \
> [v1]scale=640:360,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vout1]; \
> [v2]trim=10:15,scale=640:360,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vout2]; \
> [0:a]asplit=2[a1][a2]; \
> [a1]anull,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aout1]; \
> [a2]atrim=10:15,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aout2]; \
> [vout1][aout1]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[out1]; \
> [vout2][aout2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[out2]" \
> -map "[out1]" "/Users/Luca/Downloads/1.mp4" \
> -map "[out2]" "/Users/Luca/Downloads/2.mp4" 
ffmpeg version N-72460-gc5a07f1-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --as=yasm --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-version3 --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=qtkit --disable-indev=x11grab_xcb
  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101
  libavcodec     56. 40.100 / 56. 40.100
  libavformat    56. 33.101 / 56. 33.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/Users/Luca/Desktop/_TEMP UPLOAD/Video/Robotica_1080.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libDivXMediaFormat 4.0.0.0578
  Duration: 00:00:20.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4282 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main), yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(en): Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
[swscaler @ 0x7fb4d181c400] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7fb4d185be00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/Users/Luca/Downloads/1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.33.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.40.100 libvo_aacenc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.40.100 libvo_aacenc
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p(pc), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.40.100 libx264
Output #1, mp4, to '/Users/Luca/Downloads/2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.33.101
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p(pc), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.40.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (hevc) -> split
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> asplit
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:0 (libvo_aacenc)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (libvo_aacenc)
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:2 (libx264)
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #1:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  501 fps= 26 q=-1.0 Lq=-1.0 size=    1512kB time=00:00:19.97 bitrate= 620.1kbits/s    
video:1385kB audio:392kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] frame I:3     Avg QP:19.30  size:  3879
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] frame P:321   Avg QP:24.53  size:  3024
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] frame B:177   Avg QP:26.20  size:   825
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] consecutive B-frames: 40.7% 34.7%  5.4% 19.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] mb I  I16..4: 24.8% 65.9%  9.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] mb P  I16..4:  7.5% 10.5%  2.5%  P16..4: 22.9%  7.4%  2.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:46.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] mb B  I16..4:  0.4%  0.6%  0.3%  B16..8: 17.2%  2.9%  0.7%  direct: 0.9%  skip:77.1%  L0:37.2% L1:51.8% BI:11.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] 8x8 transform intra:51.6% inter:69.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 40.2% 24.2% 1.1% inter: 8.5% 4.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] i16 v,h,dc,p:  9% 65%  1% 25%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 29% 16%  4%  6%  6%  7%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 34% 12%  3%  7%  6%  7%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 63% 25% 11%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] ref P L0: 69.3% 11.5% 12.5%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] ref B L0: 82.4% 16.7%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] ref B L1: 98.6%  1.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d183f400] kb/s:450.44
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] frame I:1     Avg QP:22.23  size:  6699
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] frame P:78    Avg QP:24.94  size:  2998
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] frame B:46    Avg QP:27.93  size:  1036
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] consecutive B-frames: 32.0% 56.0%  2.4%  9.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] mb I  I16..4: 53.5% 26.6% 19.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] mb P  I16..4:  9.8%  7.6%  3.1%  P16..4: 25.0%  8.0%  2.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:43.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] mb B  I16..4:  0.8%  0.5%  0.4%  B16..8: 22.4%  3.5%  0.8%  direct: 1.1%  skip:70.4%  L0:41.1% L1:48.0% BI:10.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] 8x8 transform intra:36.1% inter:66.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 33.5% 24.6% 1.8% inter: 8.5% 3.8% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] i16 v,h,dc,p:  4% 82%  1% 13%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 40% 18%  3%  4%  4%  7%  3%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 40% 13%  3%  5%  5%  6%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 54% 36%  8%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] ref P L0: 60.6% 10.5% 17.5% 11.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] ref B L0: 77.6% 22.0%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] ref B L1: 99.1%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4d184e400] kb/s:461.15
```

Comment: You need to show the complete console output from each `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard added console output of first command. The second one is almost the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In concat filter, "n" defines the number of segments. so n must be "2" in your filter, like this :

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i "Robotica_1080.mkv" \
-filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[v1][v2]; \
[v1]scale=640:360,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vout1]; \
[v2]trim=10:15,scale=640:360,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vout2]; \
[0:a]asplit=2[a1][a2]; \
[a1]anull,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aout1]; \
[a2]atrim=10:15,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aout2]; \
[vout1][aout1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vout1][aout1]; \
[vout2][aout2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vout2][aout2]" \
-map [vout1] -map [aout1] "1.mp4" \
-map [vout2] -map [aout2] "2.mp4"
```

or you can just map the audio in following command :

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i "Robotica_1080.mkv" \
-filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[v1][v2]; \
[v1]scale=640:360,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vout1]; \
[v2]trim=10:15,scale=640:360,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vout2]; \
[0:a]asplit=2[a1][a2]; \
[a1]anull,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aout1]; \
[a2]atrim=10:15,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aout2]"
-map [vout1] -map [aout1] "1.mp4" \
-map [vout2] -map [aout2] "2.mp4"
```

Comment: Setting concat filter "n" to 2 gives me this error: Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 2 on filter Parsed_concat_11

Setting the mapping as your second command results in this error: Output pad "default" with type video of the filter instance "Parsed_setpts_5" of setpts not connected to any destination

Comment: Sorry i fixed few things. Can you try again with fixed command-line? In this case, I think that concat filter did nothing and just passing frames to out, so you should use the second.

Comment: Thank you! The second one works as expected! I still don't know why the concat filter doesn't do the job, but I just learned the -map option does (as per documentation: "Designate one or more input streams as a source for the output file")